# Can not use queue.put with keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing

I would like to load 3 keras model using multiprocessing but I can not get any result from function.

my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def import_model_0(ModelPath, queue):
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(ModelPath)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print('model 0 is ' ,model)
queue.put([model, '0'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  queue = Queue()
    
  model_0 = Process(target=import_model_0, args=(model_path_set[0], queue, ))
  model_1 = Process(target=import_model_1, args=(model_path_set[1], queue, ))
  model_2 = Process(target=import_model_2, args=(model_path_set[2], queue, ))
    
  model_0.start()
  model_1.start()
  model_2.start()
    
  model_0.join()
  model_1.join()
  model_2.join()
    
  print('Using time ', time.time()-ts, 'sec')
  if queue.empty() is False:
     get_model = queue.get()
     print('recieve')
     if get_model[1] == '0':
        get_model_0 = get_model[0]
        print(get_model_0)
        elif get_model[1] == '1':
        get_model_1 = get_model[0]
        print(get_model_1)
        elif get_model[1] == '2':
        get_model_2 = get_model[0]
        print(get_model_2)
```

when my code print get_model_0, get_model_1, get_model_2 its show nothing

Comment: What it the full output of the program? Do any errors occur?

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso in your case is better used a multiprocessing pool for a more clean code, do any errors occur in the execution?,